# How to make a responsive canva on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, responsive-design, tkinter-canvas, dimension

(This first edit was made before changing the title, please read till the end!)

I am having problems while adjusting the screen of Tkinter on Windows 10.

I was doing things like that:

```
width_screen  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height_screen = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(f'{width_screen}x{height_screen}')
```

But the problem is that this configuration hide my taskbar... I search a way to set the screen like as it is for my browser for example, with a maximized window and a taskbar.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT 1: It is not working with this code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

# -------------------------------- Importation ------------------------------- #

import os
import subprocess

import tkinter as tk

# ------------------------------ Initialisation ------------------------------ #

root = tk.Tk() #initialise l'application
root.title("Bruits ambiants pour l'écoute du patient")

width_screen  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height_screen = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.state('zoomed')

wav_files = ["a.wav","b.wav","c.wav","d.wav","e.wav","f.wav","g.wav","h.wav","i.wav","j.wav","k.wav","l.wav","m.wav","n.wav","o.wav","p.wav","q.wav","r.wav","s.wav","t.wav","u.wav","v.wav","w.wav","x.wav","y.wav","z.wav","aa.wav","bb.wav","cc.wav","dd.wav","ee.wav","ff.wav","gg.wav","hh.wav","ii.wav","jj.wav"]


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                            Vertical scrolled frame                           #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)            

        # Create a frame for the canvas with non-zero row&column weights
        self.frame_canvas = tk.Frame(self,bg="gray50")
        self.frame_canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nw')
        self.frame_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent=parent

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame_canvas, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame_canvas, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set, width=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth(), 
                        height=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()-100)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        vscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = tk.Frame(self.canvas,bg="gray50")
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor=tk.NW)
        self.interior.update_idletasks()

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                self.canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())

        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)
        
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        if len(wav_files) > 25:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
        

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                 Sound Buttons                                #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class Make_sound:
    def __init__(self, name, parent, i):

        self.varbutton = tk.StringVar()

        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent


        self.num = i
        self.soundbuttoncreator()

    def soundbuttoncreator(self):

        self.rows = self.num//4
        self.columns = self.num%4

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent,bg="gray50", bd=3, relief="flat") # create a frame to hold the widgets
        
        # use self.frame as parent instead of self.parent

        self.button = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text=self.name.capitalize(), indicatoron=False, selectcolor="DeepSkyBlue3", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3",variable=self.varbutton, command=self.launchsound, height=6, width=20) 
        self.button.pack()

        self.button.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.button.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        self.frame.grid(row=self.rows, column=self.columns)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self.button['background'] = 'LightSteelBlue3'

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self.button['background'] = 'slate gray'

    def launchsound(self):   
        pass


def sounds_buttons(parent):
    for i in range(len(wav_files)):
        new_name = wav_files[i][:-4]
        globals()["wav_files"][i] = Make_sound(new_name,parent,i)
            

def end_all():
    for i in range(len(wav_files)):
        globals()["wav_files"][i].varbutton.set("0")
        try:
            globals()["wav_files"][i].chan.stop()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                   Creation                                   #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# ---------------------------------- Button ---------------------------------- #

frame_test = tk.Frame(root)
frame_test.grid(row=10,column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="s",padx=5,pady=10)
Button_open = tk.Button(frame_test, text="Open", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3")
Button_open.pack(fill="x")
Button_end = tk.Button(frame_test, text="End", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3")
Button_end.pack(fill="x")


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                 LEFT BUTTONS                                 #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

frame_buttons = tk.Frame(root,bd=5,bg="gray50")
frame_buttons.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=8,padx=5,pady=10,sticky="nw")

scframe = VerticalScrolledFrame(frame_buttons)
scframe.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=20,columnspan=3)

sounds_buttons(scframe.interior)

# ----------------------------------- test ----------------------------------- #

panel = tk.Button(root, text="test", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3")
panel.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nw")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                     ROOT                                     #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

root.mainloop()
```

(Some EDITS were suppressed for your readability)

LAST EDIT:

I found out that the problem comes from a part of my class:

```
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame_canvas, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set, width=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth(), 
                        height=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()-100)
```

In fact, the `height=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()-100` part is not working properly. If I put `height=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()-1000`, here is my output:
[image]

It is promising, because I now see the frame. Now, I understand that I just want the canvas to be responsive and not to set height and width, though I can work with it many computers!

Could you please explain me a way to achieve that? Maybe for example, always having 4 columns of buttons but with their dimensions that can change, and setting the button list to always be taking the rest of the screen (we could say that it may take the half of the screen width, and that the buttons over and below must grow as the button list grows?).

Comment: `root.state('zoomed')`.

Comment: Well... I edited my post because it is not working in my configuration...

Comment: Works fine on my PC.

Comment: Oh... I edited to show you my output.

Comment: Are there some differences if you click the "maximize" button twice under these circumstances?

Comment: No, there is nothing that changes.

Comment: I found out the origin of my problem, but not the answer. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

# -------------------------------- Importation ------------------------------- #

import os
import subprocess

import tkinter as tk

# ------------------------------ Initialisation ------------------------------ #

root = tk.Tk()  # initialise l'application
root.title("Bruits ambiants pour l'écoute du patient")

width_screen = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height_screen = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.state('zoomed')

wav_files = ["a.wav", "b.wav", "c.wav", "d.wav", "e.wav", "f.wav", "g.wav", "h.wav", "i.wav", "j.wav", "k.wav", "l.wav",
             "m.wav", "n.wav", "o.wav", "p.wav", "q.wav", "r.wav", "s.wav", "t.wav", "u.wav", "v.wav", "w.wav", "x.wav",
             "y.wav", "z.wav", "aa.wav", "bb.wav", "cc.wav", "dd.wav", "ee.wav", "ff.wav", "gg.wav", "hh.wav", "ii.wav",
             "jj.wav"]


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                            Vertical scrolled frame                           #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # Create a frame for the canvas with non-zero row&column weights
        self.parent = parent

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill="y", side="right",expand=True)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=1,
                                yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        vscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="gray50")
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                                anchor=tk.NW)
        self.interior.update_idletasks()

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                self.canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())

        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        if len(wav_files) > 25:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                 Sound Buttons                                #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class Make_sound:
    def __init__(self, name, parent, i):
        self.varbutton = tk.StringVar()

        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent

        self.num = i
        self.soundbuttoncreator()

    def soundbuttoncreator(self):
        self.rows = self.num // 4
        self.columns = self.num % 4

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, bg="gray50", bd=3, relief="flat")  # create a frame to hold the widgets

        # use self.frame as parent instead of self.parent

        self.button = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text=self.name.capitalize(), indicatoron=False,
                                     selectcolor="DeepSkyBlue3", background="slate gray",
                                     activebackground="LightSteelBlue3", variable=self.varbutton,
                                     command=self.launchsound, height=6, width=20)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.button.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        self.frame.grid(row=self.rows, column=self.columns)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self.button['background'] = 'LightSteelBlue3'

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self.button['background'] = 'slate gray'

    def launchsound(self):
        pass


def sounds_buttons(parent):
    for i in range(len(wav_files)):
        new_name = wav_files[i][:-4]
        globals()["wav_files"][i] = Make_sound(new_name, parent, i)


def end_all():
    for i in range(len(wav_files)):
        globals()["wav_files"][i].varbutton.set("0")
        try:
            globals()["wav_files"][i].chan.stop()
        except AttributeError:
            pass


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                   Creation                                   #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# ---------------------------------- Button ---------------------------------- #

frame_test = tk.Frame(root)
frame_test.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="ns")
Button_open = tk.Button(frame_test, text="Open", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3")
Button_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
Button_end = tk.Button(frame_test, text="End", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3")
Button_end.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ns")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                 LEFT BUTTONS                                 #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

frame_buttons = tk.Frame(root, bd=5, bg="gray50")
frame_buttons.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=8, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nwes")

scframe = VerticalScrolledFrame(frame_buttons)
scframe.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

sounds_buttons(scframe.interior)

# ----------------------------------- test ----------------------------------- #

panel = tk.Button(root, text="test", background="slate gray", activebackground="LightSteelBlue3")
panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                     ROOT                                     #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

for i in range(1, 11):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

for i in range(frame_test.grid_size()[1]+1):
    frame_test.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Too much code,A little hard to understand your layout.
I changed a lot from your code,your `frame_buttons` doesn't use `sticky="nwes"`.So it couldn't fill in the frame.

And in the canvas, you also need to use `pack` manager(if you didn't use `sticky="nwes"` and set the `rowconfigure`, I still recommend you use `pack`).

for responsive, you need to set `gird_rowconfigure`

check the code for more details.

The output:
[image]

If there only one button on the canvas, the scrollbar is disabled:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! Could we imagine that the button grow as the window grows? Like, if I had `columnspan=3` inside `frame_buttons.grid()`, and if I delete the heights and widths of the self.button buttons. When I just do that after having looped a grid_columnconfigure in range(0.5) like you did, my buttons and the gray part have a small width, and the scrollbar isn't at the right. Thank you, mate!

Comment: @TristanN Check it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it could work on the buttons that are outside of the list of buttons (wav_files).  But as we have the list of scrolling buttons inside frames, I don't know how to achieve that for the buttons inside (make them grow inside the canva)... Also, when we don't have enough buttons to need to scroll, we still are able to scroll, which is quite strange, and I don't fin a way to desactivate (`state='disabled'` for example) the scrolling bar when it isn't needed...

Comment: So there is no way to achieve that?

Comment: @TristanN I really couldn't reproduce that, If there is only one button in the `canvas` (wav_files)?The scrollbar is disabled...

Comment: My bad, the problem is solved since we changed some parameters at the last edit. I still worry about the fact that I don't know how to make the canvas take a certain pourcentage of the free space in the screen (width and height), and the buttons could then grow in the canva always in the same proportions.

Comment: @TristanN Due to your layout is a little hard to understand, have you tried set the `rowconfigure()` in all the parent container of the button?I tried but failed, too.I have no idea.Nested parent container makes me dizzy.

Comment: Well, I found no way to do that. Still, thank you for your help.